# What is the fastest way to write an even number as the sum of two primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, computational-complexity

Assume Goldbach Conjecture and write an even number $2n$ as the sum of two primes. The obvious approach is the forward search: Start with $p=3$ and check if $2n-p$ is a prime. If yes, stops, else we proceed to check with the next prime $p=5$ and so on. An alternate approach is the backward search: Start with the largest prime $\pi(2n)$ and check if $2n-p_{\pi(2n)}$ is a prime. If yes, stop, else we proceed to check with the previous prime $p_{\pi(2n)-1}$ and so on.

For $n \le 1.03 \times 10^{10}$ I counted how many searches both approaches required before we found the first solution. The data shows that for the backward search $2n-p_{\pi(2n)}$ is the first solution in about $59\%$ of the time and $2n-p_{\pi(2n)-1}$ is the first solution nearly $20\%$ of the time. For the forward search, $2n-3$ is the first solution in only about $8.8\%$ of the cases while $2n-5$ is the first solution in only about $8.2\%$ of the cases. These percentages are expected to decreases as $n$ increases.

The graph below shows the probability that the forward and the backward requires $k = 1,2,\ldots 60$ before finding the first solution.

[image]

Notice that for $k = 1,2,3$ the backward probabilities higher while for $k \ge 4$ the forward probabilities is higher. Based on this data, an algorithm to minimize the number of searches is as follows.

```
 - Check if the largest prime q < 2n is a solution
 - If yes, stop else, check with the previous prime
 - If yes, stop else, check with the previous prime
 - If yes, stop else, start with p = 11 (corresponding to k=4) and continue searching successive primes until a solution is found
```

I implemented the forward, the backward and the above modified search and ran it for $n \le 10^{10}$. The forward search was the slowest while the modified algorithm was marginally faster than backward search. This is despite the fact the in the backward search, finding the largest prime less than $2n$, and then its previous prime and so on takes more computational time than searching for primes in ascending order $3,5,7,11, \ldots $

**Question 1**: Is there a way to improve upon the above algorithm and reduce the number of searches?

**Question 2**: What is the expected number of searches in the forward, backward and above algorithms

**Related question**: [How soon can we represent a number as the sum of two primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4354708/how-soon-can-we-represent-a-number-as-the-sum-of-two-primes)

Comment: I would suggest looking at what other people have done when setting search records on the Goldbach problem, and see whether they describe in any detail what they found was fastest. No reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: In particular, https://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach.html

Comment: With the reverse search, the number of searches may be less, but won't that be overshadowed by the time you spend identifying what $p_{\pi(2n)}$ even is? You'll be prime testing $2n-1,2n-3,\ldots$ until you find a prime. Then prime testing the complement. Because primes are more sparse at the high end of $[2,2n]$ that will be more prime testing than with the forward search. Also with a forward search you can at least use a sieve to identify the next prime to look at.

Comment: @2'59'2 No the reverse is still faster as the time lost in identifying $p_{\pi(2n)}$ is more than offset by the fact the largest prime is a solution in nearly $59\%$ of the cases. More specifically, in my SageMath implementation, by the time the backward search reached $10^{10}$ the forward search had only reached about $0.85 \times 10^{10}$ although both were started simultaneously on the same computer. Also the gap between the two was increasing with time.

Comment: Could you try with bigger numbers? I would suspect that at some point the reverse will get slower, because finding $p_{\pi(2n)}$ will become costly.

Comment: Have you had a look at the link I posted, Nilo?

Comment: There is no reason why the obvious approach (enumerating the odd primes in increasing order) is not best in general. If $N$ is very large (say several hundrede digits) then starting with $N/2$ should be slower because we have to check two large numbers for primality for every partition , in the other case only one. Checking a number with magnitude twice for primality is not significantly more difficult.

Answer (score 2):

You could apply Sieve of Eratosthenes that gives primes in a range. You can sieve the range $(2, n/2)$. The sieving takes $O(n \log \log n)$ time and $O(n)$ space.

You could then test pairs of primes in this range using a modified binary search. This is based on the fact that if $p + q = n$ with $p, q$ prime, then both $p$ and $q$ will be in the sieved results of the range $(2, n/2)$. The sieved results occupies space $N = O\left({n \over \log n}\right)$ by the Prime Number Theorem.

For a given $p$, the binary search for $q$ takes $O(\log N)$ time where $N$ is the size of the sieved results. This search may or may not succeed in finding the pair $p,q$ such that $p + q = n$.

Therefore, this takes $O(N \log N)$ time, in the worst case (actually $O({N \over 2} \log N)$, but we are ignoring the constant factor in Big-O notation).